# Automate UML from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, uml, data-modeling

currently I have a fully working project in Eclipse using OOP. Now I want to creat UML diagrams Use Cases, Sequence Diagram, class diagram, package diagram with eclipse, does eclipse or any available plugin for eclipse allow this service

Comment: Once I came across one such tool where to draw the diagram we just have to drag the java on a workspace and the appropriate model is drawn but the forgot the tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I do Eclipse 3.6 and my Java projects. Just a drag and drop from the package explorer to the class or sequence diagram. Really cool.

*-broken link to image removed-*

For usecases which are an UML object and not an Java object I drag and drop the usecases from the model explorer. I also sometimes create a class and add Usecase as stereotype. It means that my class diagram can have usecase which are related to a class. It does the job and pretty easy.

Comment: Can I know which plugin are u using

Comment: Click on the image background and you will find out the URL where this picture is coming from :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try out ModelGoon UML4Java, it can build Class, Package, Commumication, and Sequence diagrams from existing Java code. Diagrams are also built by using drag and drop. The sequence diagram is very detailed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [HiberObject](http://www.objectgeneration.com/eclipse/) plugin. Also can use [Jupe](http://jupe.binaervarianz.de/)

If you are using Eclipse 6.1 then [this](http://www.objectgeneration.com/eclipse/) could be helpful.